# SQL Server stored procedure to select only active columns in a particular order

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I want to be able to write a SQL Server stored procedure which would select columns based on a parameter and selection order should be based on another parameter.

For example, I've got a table `tblStaging` which has a few columns (Name, date, Addr1, Addr2, Addr3). I want to use this table to create an XML using a stored procedure. The stored procedure would simply select the columns from this table and display them in XML syntax, something like:

```
SELECT
    Name, date, Addr1, Addr2, Addr3 
FROM  
    tblStaging 
FOR XML RAW ('TRAN'), ROOT ('SEPA'), ELEMENTS;
```

Now, I want to make this stored procedure configurable by letting the user pass 2 parameters, namely 'Active' flag and 'Order'. Active: 1 or 0, will decide whether a field will be selected in the XML schema. Order: 1,2,3,4..will determine what order the fields will be selected in. So eg. if 'Name' is set as Active = 1 and Order = 2, it will be selected but not as 1st element but as second in the XML.

What's the best way to achieve this? Don't know if I should have 2 parameters per column and ask user to pass a value for each, it's kinda cumbersome if the table will have say 10 columns (=20 parameters).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need more info. What is the purpose of the data? Do you need all of the results or some? Is there a reason you cannot handle the order by in the framework level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a working code for you. You probably want to develop it further before you use it in production system as its not tested and subject to SQL injection.

@OrderBy : you may also use ordinal as allowed by SQL (`order by 1 ASC` will work)

@Columns : you may either use ordinal or column name

Further development can add another variable for table name, for example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample_Procedure 
    @Orderby nvarchar(100) = 'Name Asc',
    @Columns nvarchar(100) = '1,2,3,Name' 
AS
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @UsedColumns nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @X xml

/*
   Using string manipulation and covert to transform  @Columns to xml, 
   so 1,2,3 becomes: <root><s>1</s><s>2</s><s>2</s></root> and then
   converted to XML so we can select from it as if it was a table. 
   if you have SQL 2016 it's possible to replace it with STRING_SPLIT 
*/
SELECT  @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@Columns,',','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')


DECLARE @ColsTab as TABLE (Col nvarchar(100))
/*This part "shreds" the xml above into the variable table @ColsTab. 
  we need it for the `IN' operator later.
*/
INSERT  into @ColsTab (col)
SELECT  T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)


SET @UsedColumns = STUFF(   (SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME='tblStaging'
        and (COLUMN_NAME in  (Select Col from @ColsTab)
            or ORDINAL_POSITION in (Select iif(IsNumeric(Col)=1,Col,Null) from @ColsTab)
            )
                FOR XML PATH('')), 
            1, 1, '')



SET @SQLString = 'Select '+ @UsedColumns +'
from tblStaging 
order by '+@Orderby+'
FOR XML RAW (''TRAN''), ROOT (''SEPA''), ELEMENTS';

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @SQLString

RETURN
```

Same query, this time the dynamic query is also setting the ordinal of the output columns:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample_Procedure2 
    @Orderby nvarchar(100) = 'Name Asc',
    @Columns nvarchar(100) = '2,3,Name' 
AS
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @UsedColumns nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @X xml

/*
   Using string manipulation and covert to transform  @Columns to xml, 
   so 1,2,3 becomes: <root><s>1</s><s>2</s><s>2</s></root> and then
   converted to XML so we can select from it as if it was a table. 
   if you have SQL 2016 it's possible to replace it with STRING_SPLIT 
*/
SELECT  @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s>' + REPLACE(@Columns,',','</s> <s>') + '</s>   </root> ')


DECLARE @ColsTab as TABLE (Col nvarchar(100))
/*This part "shreds" the xml above into the variable table @ColsTab. 
  we need it for the `IN' operator later.
*/
INSERT  into @ColsTab (col)
SELECT  T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)


/*  This version usues left join to assume the same order of 
    columns as specified in the input field @Columns
    be mindful not to specify the same field twice
*/
SET @UsedColumns = STUFF(   (
    SELECT      ',' + i.COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM        @ColsTab as c
    LEFT JOIN   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as i
        ON      i.COLUMN_NAME = Col 
            OR  ORDINAL_POSITION = iif(IsNumeric(Col)=1,Col,Null)
    WHERE       TABLE_NAME='tblStaging'
        AND     COLUMN_NAME is not null
                FOR XML PATH('')), 
                1, 1, '')



SET @SQLString = 'Select '+ @UsedColumns +'
from tblStaging 
order by '+@Orderby+'
FOR XML RAW (''TRAN''), ROOT (''SEPA''), ELEMENTS';

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @SQLString

RETURN
```

Comment: Hi @UV, that's really helpful! I tried running the script and it does create the XML perfectly with the columns specified in `@Columns`. But it seems to be ordering the columns as they appear in the table schema not in the order specified in `@Columns` variable. Eg. I set `@Columns = '4,1,2,3'`, but the XML results still appeared in the order 1,2,3,4. The `@Orderby` variable was set to `'1 Asc'`. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Could you please help with this?

Comment: Also, I can understand bits of the code but not everything, eg. how `@X` or `@UserColumns` are assigned. It'll be great if you can explain how this is working so I am in a position to change the code as necessary or put in more conditions when needed etc. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Asher, the `@OrderBy` is for the sorting, note it's used directly  in the `Order By` section of the query. I'll add some comments to the code for you :) Cheers -- Yuval

Comment: Thanks Yuval! This works fabulously..In fact I tried specifying the same twice in `@Columns` (since I'd like some fields to appear multiple times at different orders in the XML) and it works with that too!